# Exception handling while deleting object in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

Basically I am decouple my code by introducing an *Employee Repository* to handle all the database interaction. My problem is that my code performs instruction but then throws

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'.

I have tried using `FirstOrDefault` and `SingelOrDefault` as suggested but previous posts I've read but it performs the remove operation and throws

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

`removeEmployee` was null. Can someone help explain to me how to fix it

This is the code I am trying to refactor and this initial code worked without throwing an exception:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Remove(int[] employeeIds)
{ 

    foreach (int employeeId in employeeIds)
    {
        Employee removeEmployee = context.Employees.Single(c => c.EmployeeID == employeeId);

        if (removeEmployee.WorkStatus == "Available")
        {
           context.Employee.Remove(removeEmployee);
        }
        else
        {
           return Redirect("/Employee/Remove");
        }

   }
   context.SaveChanges();
   return Redirect("/");
}
```

Below is how I am trying to refactor my code.

Employee Repoistory:

```
 public bool RemoveEmployee(int[] employeeIds)
    {
        foreach (int employeeId in employeeIds)
        {
            Employee removeEmployee = context.Employees.Single(c => c.EmployeeID == employeeId);

            if (removeEmployee.WorkStatus == "Available")
            {
                context.Employees.Remove(removeEmployee);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Employee Controller:

```
private IEmployeesRepository repo;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeesRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Remove(int[] employeeIds)
    {
        repo.RemoveEmployee(employeeIds);

        if (repo.RemoveEmployee(employeeIds) == false)
        {
            return Redirect("/Employee/Remove");
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: here's your problem right here: `Employee removeEmployee = context.Employees.Single(c => c.EmployeeID == employeeId);`

Comment: See the docs, it returns InvalidOperationException when the predicated function yields 0 results and NullReferenceException if any of the items being evaluated are null. I am still reading the title part over to try to understand what you mean by "but still performs instructions".

Comment: About the only way it could "still work" would be if you did the worst thing and swallowed the exceptions. Here are two articles on proper exception handling that I link quite often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @RossBush the code does what I want it to do except that it throws the exception and crashes. it wouldn't remove/delete object from table if it null. my code worked perfectly well before I tried to refactor it. I just don't understand what I am doing wrong this time

Comment: @Christopher I understand exception handling could fix my problem. I just don't understand why the initial code works just fine without exception handling but the little change I made is breaking my code. Understanding what I am doing wrong is actually more important to me

Comment: @JohnB please could explain further?

Comment: @iyke: Please define "works perfectly fine on a exception". That is a Oxymoron. You either have a exception. Or it works fine. You can not have both. Especially not with the **same** Operation.

Comment: @Christopher it worked initially without crashing until I tried to make the changes

Comment: it's crazy bug in your action controller!! actually you are calling `RemoveEmployee` twice, one before `if..` and one in `if..`, and in the second call you get exception since the Ids are not existed any more

Comment: @ElyasEsna AH!!! Thank You. That was my problem

Comment: @ElyasEsna Thank you for taking time to look at the code. I'm relatively new to coding so I make silly mistakes that this one and end up driving myself crazy

Answer (score 0):

As Ross Bush pointed out, the line of code mentioned by JohnB throws invalid operation exception if the predicate (c => c.EmployeeID == employeeId) yields 0 results when your method is just 'Single'. If you put 'SingleOrDefault' the result will be null. So "removeEmployee" will be null. When you access any member under removeEmployee which is now null (like "removeEmployee.WorkStatus"), it will throw the null reference exception.

I am not sure how your code worked before. Your first version of code has context.Employee, but your modified version has context.Employees. I suspect there is something going on there or it might be that when you tested with the original code, there might have been some data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody that bothered to look at my problem and tried to help me find a solution. The problem with my code actually had to do with the logic in my "RemoveEmployee" Method and the return Boolean value. Below is the solution I came up with.

Employee Repository:

```
public bool RemoveEmployee(int[] employeeIds)
        {
            foreach (int employeeId in employeeIds)
            {
                Employee removeEmployee = context.Employees.Single(c => c.EmployeeID == employeeId); 
                if (removeEmployee !=null && removeEmployee.WorkStatus == "Available")
                {
                    context.Employees.Remove(removeEmployee);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }        
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Employeee Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Remove(int[] employeeIds)
        {                   
            if (repo.RemoveEmployee(employeeIds) == false)
            {
                return Redirect("/Employee/Remove");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/Employee");
            }
        }
```